# How to delete date space in Google Charts and correct percentage display

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a lot of values since 30 Nov 2015 to 29 Feb 2019. Since 29 Feb to 11 Apr  is nothing, and then new values after 11 Apr.
If I use "date" type of axe, I will have a big space beetwen 29 Feb and 11 Apr: http://white-fund.com/#roiPage (left chart)
If I use string type of axe, I will have no grouping (no few days in 1 element) and no display by month.

I need date format, grouping and no space, like I get it in Excel: http://white-fund.com/pictures/total_roi.png

Code:

```
    function drawChart() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'x');
    data.addColumn('number', 'ROI per day');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Total ROI');

    <?php   
$db = new db();
$ROIRows = $db->select("roi");
if($ROIRows) foreach ($ROIRows as $ROIRow) {
    echo "data.addRow([new Date(\"$ROIRow[date_time]\"), ". ($ROIRow['roi']/100) .", ". ($ROIRow['total_roi']/100) ."]);";
}

?>


    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ 
      pattern: '#,###%', 
      fractionDigits: 2
    }); 
    formatter.format(data, 1);
    formatter.format(data, 2);


  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).
      draw(data, {curveType: "function", width: 540, height: 290,
    vAxes:{
        0: {title:'ROI per day', format: 'percent'},
        1: {title:'Total ROI', format: 'percent'}
        },
    series:{
       0:{targetAxisIndex:0, type: 'bars', logScale:false},
       1:{targetAxisIndex:1, type: 'line', pointSize:7, logScale:false},
       },

       seriesType: 'bars'

       }
          );

}
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

Another one problem: how to display percents in float, not int? I trying to use formatter, but it shows 272.52% as 273%.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To fill-in gaps, add `interpolateNulls: true` to your [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options)...

As for the number format, try this pattern --> `'#,##0.00%'`
and lose `fractionDigits: 2`

Comment: interpolateNulls: true has no effect

Comment: I think that's because I don't have values with nulls in gap. I have no values in gap

Comment: added
data.addRow([new Date('2016-03-02'), null, null]);
data.addRow([new Date('2016-03-05'), null, null]);
data.addRow([new Date('2016-03-07'), null, null]);
data.addRow([new Date('2016-03-15'), null, null]);
data.addRow([new Date('2016-03-18'), null, null]);
data.addRow([new Date('2016-03-22'), null, null]);
data.addRow([new Date('2016-03-28'), null, null]);

but nothing changed

Comment: Documentation writes about interpolateNulls: "If true, it will guess the value of any missing data based on neighboring points.". But it already shows missing data based on neighboring points. I need show based on real points without gap (like in Excel).

Comment: ok, I misunderstood -- what if you remove / hide the rows with `null` (don't draw them) -- would that work? you could exclude them in your php `foreach` or after the fact with a `DataView`...?

Comment: to use a `DataView` -- pass array of null data row indexes to `DataView.hideRows(array)`

Comment: "php foreach addRow" adds only values (red points at chart), without any nulls. if I use code in topic or if I use addRow to add rows with nulls (with interpolateNulls: true option), I always have same result: March gap, http://snag.gy/oH4fm.jpg